# Office 2013 Interop on Server 2012: Word freezing host

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word, office-interop

First a bit of background: I KNOW that MS Office interop is not supported in a server environment.  I was told to make it work anyway.

I have inherited a project from a developer who has left the company.  The project involves converting arbitrary 1-2 page documents uploaded to our website by users to PDF format.  The documents are a variety of primarily Office documents.  Off the top of my head we accept doc, docx, txt, and rtf documents and possibly others.  The documents must be made available at a later date both in the original format and PDF format.  The developer decided that the best way to accomplish this was by using MS Office interop and letting Word handle the conversion.

On his workstation and on mine it works pretty well, but as soon as the site is published to a server it fails.  It doesn't just fail though, Word opens up and consumes more and more and more memory until it finally locks up the server and the server must be power-cycled.

I have been beating my head over this for a while now.  Most of the other people online I have found having trouble have reported an error message, but I have not found anyone reporting that the server simply locks up.  And yet, I have observed exactly the same behavior on three different servers.  I tried wrapping the code in a windows service (as opposed to an aspx page in IIS) and observed the same behavior.  I wrapped the code in a winforms application and it worked just fine.  The essentials can be found below:

```
    Dim wordApplication As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass = New ApplicationClass()
    Dim wordDocument As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document = Nothing
    Try
        wordDocument = wordApplication.Documents.Open(CType(fileUrl, Object), False, True)

        If wordDocument IsNot Nothing Then
            wordDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(pdfUrl, WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF)
        End If
    Finally
        If wordDocument IsNot Nothing Then
            wordDocument.Close(False)
            wordDocument = Nothing
        End If

        If wordApplication IsNot Nothing Then
            wordApplication.Quit()
            wordApplication = Nothing
        End If

        GC.Collect()
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
        GC.Collect()
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
    End Try
```

Has anyone else dealt with an issue like this?

Answer (score 0):

The resolution required a couple steps:

It appears that the freezing was caused by the wordApplication.Quit() call.  Passing in False to suppress the save dialog resolved the freeze.  Documents still were not opening though...

For that, I had to open windows\System32\comexp.msc, and select the Properties context menu option on "Console Root" > "Component Services" > "Computers" > "My Computer" > "DCOM Config" > "Microsoft Word 97 - 2003 Document".  On the Identity tab, select "The interactive user." instead of "The launching user."

On another server, that was all I had to do to resolve the issue, but if that isn't enough, this thread has a number of other possible resolutions:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0f5448a7-72ed-4f16-8b87-922b71892e07/word-2007-documentsopen-returns-null-in-aspnet